# Restricting conversion of function pointers

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer

I wonder why a `static_cast` from `int (*)(const int&)` to type `int (*)(int&)` is illegal. If I have a function pointer that technically allows accepting an `int&` but want to assign to it a function which *voluntarily waives the permission* to modify the pointed-to value, shouldn't it behave just as a special case of a function that in principle *could*?

In other words, given that I can pass an arbitrary `int&` to an `int (*)(const int&)` function, is there a deeper reason in the standard why the latter can't be considered a special case of `int (*)(int&)` and assigned to such variable?

[M(!W)E](https://godbolt.org/g/C9ncxN):

```
int g(const int& q) {
  return q;
}

int main() {
  int (*f)(int&) = static_cast<int(*)(int&)>(g); // breaks
  int x = 1;
  return f(x);
}
```

Comment: They are different types and the standard is explicit about this kind of casts. What's unclear exactly? Do you want to know the reasons of the committee?

Comment: There is no need for the compiler to pass a reference to the const version.  It might just be implemented as const int.

Comment: Well, that would be the best. I know they are different types (hence the explicit cast), my question is why incompatible.

Comment: @TheVee It's how `static_cast` works. They are completely different types, it won't work any time soon with them. It would compile if you used `reinterpret_cast` because of how it works instead, hence it's undefined behavior and I'm not suggesting to use it.

Comment: The conversion rules aren't sophisticated enough and don't have covariant parameters. Feel free to propose a change.

Comment: I don't like this behavior either. It is problematic with not just const/non-const, but with covariant types. The standard should allow this. Currently, I use `reinterpret_cast` for this case (I know, it is UB, but it actually works with all compilers I use), because I don't want to pay the price of the extra wrapper function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] is there a deeper reason in the standard why [...]

These questions are typically impossible to answer. Maybe nobody thought of it as a worthwhile thing to look into. C++ in general has limited support for covariance and contravariance. There are plenty of other safe conversions that are potentially possible, not just qualifying the references.

For instance, a function pointer like `Animal*(*)(Dog*)` could be initializeable from both `Animal*(*)(Animal*)` and `Dog*(*)(Dog*)`. But today, neither conversion is supported.

So the real answer is probably: [write a proposal](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal).

---

However, in this case, we can still accomplish the desired behavior through a clearly underappreciated rule: Almost Always Lambda.  We know, by name, the function we want to use, and lambdas without capture (which we don't need) can be converted into function pointers:

```
int (*f)(int&) = [](int& i) { return g(i); };
```

Comment: You can convert a `T *` to `T const*` _and_ you can also __view `T *` as `T const*`__ so you can convert `T * *` to `T const* const*` etc. You can convert `Der *` to `Base *` but **you cannot view a `Der *` as `Base *`**, so you cannot convert `Der * *` to `Base *const*`

Comment: @curiousguy What?

Comment: You can take an object of type `T*` and read it via an lvalue of type `T const *`, but you cannot read it via an lvalue of type `U *` related by inheritance.

Comment: @curiousguy a) You can... `Base* b = new Derived` b) I still don't understand what your comments have to do with the question or the answer.

Comment: You can `float f = 1` but an `int` is not a `float`! You can't `int i; float &f = i;` and while `int i; float &f = (float&)i;` is well formed but behavior is not defined. OTOH `int const &rci = i;` is OK and does not create a copy of current value `i` (it does not access `i` at all, `i` might be uninit). `const float &rcf = i;` is OK but does a copy of current value of `i` (value of `i` must be defined).

Comment: "_You can... `Base* b = new Derived`_" You can convert a pointer value. Decompose that in elementary steps: `Derived *pd = new Derived; Base *pb = pd;` Second declaration reads the value of `d`. Contrast with `Derived *&rpd = pd` which bind a ref without reading the value. Now consider: `Base *&prb = pd;` that is ill formed. You cannot do such ref binding. When you do `Base (*const (&prb)) = pd;` (parentheses not needed but added for clarity) a copy of `pd` is made (value is read and must be defined).